# Сочетание с предлогом "в отличие от"

Tags: синтаксис

Вот предложение:

Дома, в отличие от спортивного зала, тренироваться очень трудно.

Каким членом предложения является сочетание "в отличие от спортивного зала".

Дома — обстоятельство места.

В отличие от спортивного зала — тоже обстоятельство, но какое?

Answer (score 2):

1) Дома, в отличие от спортивного зала, тренироваться очень трудно.

Это п**ростое предложение, осложненное обособленным обстоятельственным оборотом.** Отметим, что оборот не входит в состав простого предложения, не является его членом, так как это самостоятельная синтаксическая единица.

2) **Грамматика обособленных членов**

Обособленные члены  не являются членами предложения и не образуют словосочетания с подчиняющим словом. В этом случае связь не подчинительная (управление, согласование, примыкание), а полупредикативная.

Обособленные члены **синонимичны придаточным предложениям** и занимают среднее положение между словосочетанием и придаточным предложением.

3) В данном случае "в отличие от спортивного зала" является обособленным обстоятельственным оборотом со значением **сравнения и сопоставления**. Оборот является **аналогом придаточного обстоятельственного предложения с тем же значением.**

**Сравнить:** Дома тренироваться очень трудно, если сравнивать такую тренировку с тренировкой в спортивном зале. То же содержание, только в более краткой форме, передает обстоятельственный оборот.

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл, похоже, ответ сам.

"Дома — тренироваться трудно", "но спортзале (в отличие от дома) — всё хорошо, трудностей нет".

Значит, этот оборот с предлогом есть обстоятельство сравнения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]